# Expand DataFrame by range

Tags: python, pandas

It is needed to duplicate the index of `dataframe` from `0` to `value` in column. Is there a (vectorized) way to expand this `df1` to `df2`? Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(range(3), index=range(3000, 3003))
      0
3000  0
3001  1
3002  2

df2 = ???
      0
3000  0
3001  0
3001  1
3002  0
3002  1
3002  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index.repeat(df1[0] + 1)]
df1[0] = df1.groupby(0).cumcount()
print (df1)
      0
3000  0
3001  0
3001  1
3002  0
3002  1
3002  2
```

For `Series` use [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html):

```
s = df1.index.repeat(df1[0] + 1).to_series()
s = s.groupby(s).cumcount()
print (s)
3000    0
3001    0
3001    1
3002    0
3002    1
3002    2
dtype: int64
```

and `DataFrame` from `Series` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = s.groupby(s).cumcount().to_frame()
print (df)
      0
3000  0
3001  0
3001  1
3002  0
3002  1
3002  2
```